# Laravel whereSlug not working

Tags: php, mysql, model, laravel-5

When I want to search for a ticket in laravel with a slug like this:

```
 public function showTicket(Request $slug)
{
     $ticket = Ticket::whereSlug($slug)->firstOrFail();
     if(Auth::user()->id == $ticket->user_id)
     {
        return view('users.ticket')->with('ticket',$ticket);
     }
}
```

I receive the error:

```
> ModelNotFoundException in Builder.php line 157:
No query results for model [App\Ticket].
in Builder.php line 157
at Builder->firstOrFail() in UserTicketsController.php line 66
at UserTicketsController->showTicket(object(Request), '5627caed7b3bb')
at call_user_func_array(array(object(UserTicketsController), 'showTicket'), array(object(Request), 'slug' => '5627caed7b3bb')) in Controller.php line 256
at Controller->callAction('showTicket', array(object(Request), 'slug' => '5627caed7b3bb')) in ControllerDispatcher.php line 164
at ControllerDispatcher->call(object(UserTicketsController), object(Route), 'showTicket') in ControllerDispatcher.php line 112
at ControllerDispatcher->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request))
```

And this error:

> NotFoundHttpException in Handler.php line 46: No query results for
>   model [App\Ticket]. in Handler.php line 46 at
>   Handler->render(object(Request), object(ModelNotFoundException)) in
>   Kernel.php line 281 at Kernel->renderException(object(Request),
>   object(ModelNotFoundException)) in Kernel.php line 91 at
>   Kernel->handle(object(Request)) in index.php line 54

But when I do this:

```
$ticket = Ticket::whereId(1)->firstOrFail();
```

It works? So it can find the model. I have now idea what could be wrong. When I look into the database the slug exists also when I click on a ticket the url is right this is my route:

```
Route::get('ticket/{slug?}','UserTicketsController@showTicket');
```

Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using `Request` class try this:

```
$ticket = Ticket::whereSlug($slug->get('id'))->firstOrFail();
```

If you are passing an argument do not use `Request` type.

```
public function showTicket($slug)
{
    $ticket = Ticket::whereSlug($slug)->firstOrFail();
```

Comment: Thankyou that worked. Have searched an hour for this -_-.